# Can you plug DVD/Game system into an LCD?

Tags: lcd, dvi, vga, s-video

All the LCD's in our house have DVI and VGA inputs. None support S-Video or any analog formats.

Our game systems (nes, snes, n64, ps, ps2, gamecube, etc..) and DVD and VHS players only have composite (the yellow/red/white cords..?) or S-Video (that PS2-input like cable..?).

How can I convert the signal these analog systems output to work on VGA or DVI?

Comment: Remember its from "S-Video to VGA/DVI" (DVD to LCD) which is hard to do and not "VGA to S-Video" (PC to TV) which is simple.

Comment: I'm not really sure we are still in Super User's scope. I mean, it is around a computer LCD, but the question is really about connectors between things which are out of the scope. In doubt, though, not voting to close.

Comment: No, this does not belong on SuperUser. The faq explicitly prohibits gaming and game-console related questions.

Comment: This question may not belong on SuperUser, but it has more up votes than any other question listed on the first page.

Comment: this is slightly gray area because it's a computer monitor, but it's really a question about *home theater equipment* which is offtopic here.  try [Home4Film](http://home4film.com) or another [StackExchange site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites)

Comment: I used the game consoles as an example. I'm interested in the DVD/VHS on LCD thing. But man! I had no idea there were so many SE sites! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[s-video to VGA here](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=N82E16817707055)

[List of devices here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=composite+to+vga&x=0&y=0)

*update* : found some cheaper connectors on [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=vga+to+composite+cable&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=3560713707&ref=pd_sl_31sazteisc_b)

good luck my friend!

Comment: geez, anything less than $150 xD

Comment: @Xeoncross: Remember its from "S-Video to VGA/DVI" (DVD to LCD) which is hard to do ... :)

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be done, but you'll need the right adapter for the job. Check newegg, amazon, Radio Shack, etc for whatever adapter you need (ie S-Video to VGA, etc, etc). Some of these most certainly exist and others may not.